# How to get the points where a poins pass through?

Tags: java, geometry, java-2d

I'm trying to get all points that my Shape object pass through, I have tried to transform in a Path2D object and then get the PathIterator, but the PathIterator object is a kind weird ( yeah, I don't know how to use it). So... I would like to know if there is any way to do it without calculating.

Thank you Very much!

Comment: What do you mean all the points?  Mathematically the number of points is greater than counting infinity, aleph null and is equal to continuous infinite, C. I'm not sure your question is fully answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try FlatteningPathIterator?